# error in flutter the url_launcher is not working

Tags: http, flutter

I'm trying to use `url_launcher` so that I can view articles by URL but I get a `MissingPluginException`. Can someone help me? Here's some of my code:

```
Widget _builder(Article article){
  return new Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: ListTile(
      title: new Text(article.text,style: TextStyle(
       fontSize: 24.0,
      ),
    ),
    subtitle: new Text(article.by),
    onTap: () async {
      final fakeUrl='www.${article.domain}';
      if (await canLaunch(fakeUrl)){
        launch(fakeUrl);
      } else print("could not be opened");
    ),
  );
}
```

Here's my error:

```
E/flutter (18223): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method canLaunch on channel plugins.flutter.io/url_launcher)
E/flutter (18223): #0      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:319:7)
E/flutter (18223): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (18223): #1      MethodChannelUrlLauncher.canLaunch (package:url_launcher_platform_interface/method_channel_url_launcher.dart:18:21)
E/flutter (18223): #2      canLaunch (package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart:108:45)
E/flutter (18223): #3      _MyHomePageState._builder.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_apps/main.dart:62:23)
E/flutter (18223): #4      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:706:14)
E/flutter (18223): #5      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:789:36)
E/flutter (18223): #6      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24)
E/flutter (18223): #7      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:486:11)
E/flutter (18223): #8      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:264:5)
E/flutter (18223): #9      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:236:7)
E/flutter (18223): #10     GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:156:27)
E/flutter (18223): #11     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:222:20)
E/flutter (18223): #12     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:198:22)
E/flutter (18223): #13     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:156:7)
E/flutter (18223): #14     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:102:7)
E/flutter (18223): #15     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:86:7)
E/flutter (18223): #16     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1138:13)
E/flutter (18223): #17     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1031:19)
E/flutter (18223): #18     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:933:7)
E/flutter (18223): #19     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:273:10)
E/flutter (18223): #20     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:182:5)
```

Comment: Hello. Welcome to StackOverflow. You have not asked a question. Please check the guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You should clean your project by `Flutter clean`.
If still remains You should upgrade your flutter repo by `Flutter upgrade` and the issue will be resolved for sure.You can track [this issue here.](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/10967)